# Python3においてクラス外の関数内で渡されたインスタンスのメンバ変数を変更した場合に、そのメンバ変数の変更は関数の外でも適用されるかどうか?

Tags: python, python3

以下のような処理をPython3で実行した場合に、modelのハイパーパラメータ(メンバ変数)の値の変更は関数learnの外でも適用されてしまうのでしょうか?
また、メンバ変数の変更が行われるにせよ行われないにせよそのような動作をするのは何故でしょうか?
どなたか分かる方がいらっしゃればご教授頂けると助かります。
(Jupyter Notebook上でのコード実行を想定しています。)

```
class Model:
    def train(self,..):
    #ハイパーパラメータ(メンバ変数)の値を変える処理

def learn(model):
    model.train()

model = Model()
learn(model)
```

Comment: 機械学習タグが付いていますが、Pythonのクラスの仕様についての質問ですよね？

Comment: 機械学習のコードを書く人であれば、似たようなコードを書いて同じような疑問に行き当たったことがあると推測し機械学習タグをつけました。質問内容の本質とは関係が無いのでこのタグは外すべきですか?

Comment: 個人的には、「似たようなコードを書くから」という理由でタグを付けるのは不適切に感じます。Pythonに詳しいが機械学習に詳しくない方が避けてしまう場合もあるし、機械学習について調べていた人が興味のない質問を踏んでしまう可能性があるからです。 / ちなみに、Pythonでは行末のセミコロンは不要です。

Comment: 了解です。ご指摘の通り編集します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

インスタンスを作成したときに変数に代入されるのは、インスタンスそのものではなくて、作成されたインスタンスへの参照です。ほかの変数への代入や関数呼び出しの引数に渡されるのは、全て、参照です。

```
class Apple:
    color = 'green'

    def __init__(self, _id):
        self.id = _id

    def ripen(self):
        self.color = 'red'

def change_color(apple):
    apple.ripen()

def main():
    first_apple = Apple(1)

    change_color(first_apple)
```

上のコードで、`main()`から`change_color(first_apple)`を呼んだ時点で、インスタンスがどのように参照されているかを図示すると

```
main()
    first_apple ---------------------+
                                     |
change_color()                       |
    apple -----------------------+   |
                                 |   |
                                 V   V
  Apple(1)で作られたインスタンス +-------+
                               | id    |
                               | color |
                               +-------+
```

となり、つまり`main`内の`first_apple`も、`change_color`内の'apple'も、同じインスタンスを指しています。同じインスタンスなので、`change_color`で中身を変えれは、`main`でも変わった中身が見えるわけです。

Answer (score 2):

ご指摘の通り、Python3においてはクラス変数への変更は、関数の中であるか外であるかにかかわらず、複数のインスタンスで共有されます。

```python
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/207128
>>> class A: foo = []
>>> a, b = A(), A()
>>> a.foo.append(5)
>>> b.foo
[5]
```

[Python3の公式ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)には次の通り説明があります。

> 一般的に、インスタンス変数はそれぞれのインスタンスについて固有のデータのためのもので、クラス変数はそのクラスのすべてのインスタンスによって共有される属性やメソッドのためのものです:
>   名前とオブジェクトについて で議論したように、共有データはリストや辞書のような mutable オブジェクトが関与すると驚くべき効果を持ち得ます。例えば、以下のコードの tricks リストはクラス変数として使われるべきではありません、なぜならたった一つのリストがすべての Dog インスタンスによって共有されることになり得るからです:

同時に、

> このクラスの正しい設計ではインスタンス変数を代わりに使用するべきです:

と説明されているとおり、このような用途においては常にインスタンス変数を使用するべきです。

「何故なのか」という質問に答えるのは難しいですが、[stackoverflow英語版の同様の質問への回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34126204)では「以下のような場合にクラス変数を用いるべき」と説明されています。

- 数学定数など、不変の値を保存する場合
- インスタンスにおけるデフォルトの値を定義する場合

お役に立てれば幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

まず、Python3ではメンバ変数ではなくクラス変数、及びインスタンス変数と言います。

[9. クラス — Python 3.7.4rc1 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

その上で回答すると、 **どのように値をセットしたかによって変わります**。

以下に、インスタンス変数をセットしたもの、クラス変数を変更した例を示します。

```py
class Apple:
    color = 'green'

    def __init__(self, _id):
        self.id = _id

    def ripen(self):
        self.color = 'red'

    def ripen_apple_class(self):
        Apple.color = 'rainbow'


def main():
    first_apple = Apple(1)
    second_apple = Apple(2)
    third_apple = Apple(3)

    print("================ At first")
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=first_apple))
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=second_apple))
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=third_apple))

    first_apple.ripen()
    print("================ After first apple ripen")
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=first_apple))
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=second_apple))
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=third_apple))

    first_apple.ripen_apple_class()
    print("================ All apple ripen")
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=first_apple))
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=second_apple))
    print("Apple #{apple.id}: {apple.color}".format(apple=third_apple))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

出力

```
================ At first
Apple #1: green
Apple #2: green
Apple #3: green
================ After first apple ripen
Apple #1: red
Apple #2: green
Apple #3: green
================ All apple ripen
Apple #1: red
Apple #2: rainbow
Apple #3: rainbow
```

Comment: つまりインスタンス変数はどの関数内でいじっても変更が適用されてしまう感じなんですかね...。